# How to show a partially circle spinner blocked

Tags: ios, uitableview

The code below sets the constraints of a circle spinner in a table view's footer. As shown in the [gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/Z6wKARZ5DEcrVPSOYK/giphy.gif), the circle spinner is covered by the friend(1) label. I don't what the circle spinner to be covered; how can I fix this ?

```
    tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
//    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    tableView.register(FriendsHeaderCell.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: headerReuse)
    tableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuse)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    
    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
        make.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
    
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.tintColor = .clear
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshUserData(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    // loading view for friends list
    loadingIndicator = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: refreshControl.bounds, type: .circleStrokeSpin, color: Constants.loadingIndictorColor)
    loadingIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    refreshControl.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    loadingIndicator.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.centerX.equalTo(tableView)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean you want the spinner to be vislble through the cell, you'd need to make the cell and its content view and the label have a transparent background color (`.clear`). But perhaps that isn't what you mean?

Comment: Yes that what I am trying to describe.

Comment: Well then my first comment is your answer.